# JSF Перенос строки таблицы в контроллер и обратно в следующий вид JSF

Tags: java-ee, jsf

Вcем привет!

Помогите разобраться с задачей.

Вывожу таблицу с базы данных на страницу:

```
    <h:dataTable value="#{garageController.manufacturers}" var="manufacturer"
                 styleClass = "garageTable"
                 headerClass = "tableHeader"
                 rowClasses = "tableOddRow, tableEvenRow">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet class = "header" name = "header">
                <h:outputText value = "Manufacturer Code"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value = "#{manufacturer.manu_code}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet class = "header" name = "header">
                <h:outputText value = "Manufacturer Name"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value = "#{manufacturer.manu_name}"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet class = "header" name = "header">
                <h:outputText value = "Manufacturer Details"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value = "#{manufacturer.manu_details}"/>
        </h:column>
```

В `GarageController` держу список:

```
private ArrayList<Garage> manufacturers;
    /* Getting ArrayList */
public ArrayList<Garage> getManufacturers() {
    return manufacturers;
}
```

Задача: сохранить выбранную строку таблицы как объект в контроллере `UpdateManufcturerController`, а на другую странице поставить значения переменных этого объекта как дефолт на строках ввода.

В последнию колонку таблицы вставил "кнопку":

```
<h:column>
   <f:facet class = "header" name = "header">
      <h:outputText value = "Action"/>
   </f:facet>
   <h:commandLink value = "update" action = "#{UpdateManufcturerController.sendToUpdate}">
       <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{UpdateManufcturerController.manu_code}" value="#{manufacturer.manu_code}" />
   </h:commandLink>
</h:column>
```

В контроллере создаю объект для хранения выбраной строки и перевожу на другую страницу по нажатию кнопки:

```
package ie.gmit.sw;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UpdateManufcturerController {

    // local objects
    private DAO dao;
    private Garage manufacturer;


    public Garage getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(Garage manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    /* Constructor that creates instance of DAO to communicate with database and manipulate data */
    public UpdateManufcturerController() {

        try {
            dao = new DAO();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


     public String sendToUpdate(){
          return "update-manufacturer";
     }

}
```

По нажатию кнопки выкидывает такую ошибку:

```
HTTP Status 500 - /manage-manufacturers.xhtml @54,123 
target="#{UpdateManufcturerController.manu_code}": Target Unreachable,
identifier 'UpdateManufcturerController' resolved to null
```

P.S.
Проходим как модуль семестра по курсу, опыта в JSF нету...
Может есть способы лучше справиться с этой задачей??

Благодарен за помощь и критику!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мало того, что чего-то не так делаете (раз не работает), так ещё руководствуетесь какими-то допотопными руководствами. Сейчас можно делать проще.

Начиная как минимум с JSF 2.0, `action`ами могут быть методы с параметрами.

На странице

```
<h:commandLink value = "update" 
       action = "#{updateManufcturerController.sendToUpdate(manufacturer.manu_code)}"/>
```

Метод контролёра

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UpdateManufcturerController {
    ...
    public String sendToUpdate(Object manu_code) { // не знаю какого типа manu_code 
                                                   // только поэтому пишу Object
        Garage manu = dao.findByCode(manu_code); // Предполагаю, что должно
                                                 // быть что-то для поиска 
                                                 // Garage по коду
        setManufacturer(manu);
        return "update-manufacturer";
    }
    ...
}
```

Можете так же передавать сразу Garage
Страница

```
<h:commandLink value = "update" 
       action = "#{updateManufcturerController.sendToUpdate(manufacturer)}"/>
```

Контролёр

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UpdateManufcturerController {
    ...
    public String sendToUpdate(Garage manu) {
        setManufacturer(manu);
        return "update-manufacturer";
    }
    ...
}
```

Что касается конкретно вопроса, то `identifier 'UpdateManufcturerController' resolved to null` как бы намекает: "Нет такого имени `UpdateManufcturerController`". Что не удивительно, ведь по умолчанию имя начинается с маленькой буквы `updateManufcturerController`.

Comment: Спасибо Сергей! 
Где можно почитать хорошее руководство или гайд? 

Извини, пока не набил рейтинг +15 не могу поднять ответ на +1..

Comment: Даже не знаю что и посоветовать. Обрывочные сведения из гугля, спецификация, stack overflow аглицкий, ответы чувака BalusC. У него и свой сайт есть. pdf как-то скачал Ed Burns, Chris Schalk - JavaServer Faces 2.0, The Complete Reference - McGraw-Hill, 2010 но так и не читал. Сейчас актуальная версия JSF 2.2, в который добавлено немного очень полезных функций.

Comment: Сергей, по вашему мнению в чём хорошь JSF? Почему его используют в написании веб аппликаций? Что сейчас в тренде и стоит изучать?

Comment: Наиболее популярный конкурент JSF-у и всему стеку JavaEE, как мне кажется, Spring framework. Spring использует JSP. JSP как бы из коробки, но так же можно прикрутить к нему другие библиотеки рендеринга представлений разной степени приметивности (есть довольно интересные разработки). Потом есть front-end полностью базирующийся на стороне клиента. Если бы владел javascript, то пошёл бы этим путём. Но там такое обилие вариантов, что как малограмотный ничего сказать не могу. Мне более импонирует react.js. На сервере при этом  только RESTful

Comment: Ваш ответ понятен. 
Спасибо! 
Хорошего Вам вечера. :)